# Why no children?

Tags: character, breaking-bad

In *Breaking Bad* it seemed that the Schraders loved White's kids very much and enjoyed having them in their place. Is there in-series explanation why they didn't have their own?
Same question about the Schwartzs -- they weren't young, had more than enough money and still didn't have any children.

Comment: Probably the same reason I have no kids. I like OPKs well enough; just take them when you leave.

Comment: Also, some people just miss their opportunity because they're busy with other parts of life... or they physically **can't**. The end goal of modern life doesn't require progeny and a lot of people aren't making it a priority the way they did 30-60 years ago

Comment: @Catija I'm not so sure if it was as much a priority 30-60 years ago as it was a lack of other forms of entertainment. :)

Comment: @RoboKaren I'll take that as a joke... because otherwise I'd have to start talking about stuff that really doesn't belong here. :P

Comment: Just a joke- **"Children and Dogs only looks good when they are not yours."**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There was never a reason given, and [Betsy Brandt can only speculate herself](http://www.rollingstone.com/movies/news/breaking-bad-q-a-betsy-brandt-on-maries-purple-reign-20130822):

> **I think Hank and Marie would love to have those kids.** I always felt
> like there was this undercurrent of sadness when they have Skyler and
> Walt's kids in their house, because **I think they probably wanted kids
> and couldn't have them.** I don't know if they talked about it or not,
> if it even got that far, or it just didn't happen and that was it and
> they just left it. It didn't work out that way.

That's her answer to an interesting question by Sean T. Collins that might hint at a possible motive the writers had for this situation:

> Hank and Marie have no kids of their own, and **no family to speak of**
> other than Skyler, Walt and the kids. The spark for Marie's attempt to
> take Holly was finding out about Walt and Skyler, of course, but it
> looked like she and Hank were dealing with a lot of unspoken pain
> during that scene, too.

---

Dean Norris also touches on that theme of Hank and Marie being alone and having no family in [this interview](http://www.rollingstone.com/tv/news/dean-norris-explains-hanks-moral-code-on-breaking-bad-20130912):

> This season, when Walt and Hank square off in the garage, the look you
> give him is chilling. What were you thinking about to summon that
> expression?
>
> We went through a little rehearsal on that scene. At first, it was
> much more violent. We realized that rage was just a part of it. He
> also feels hurt and fear. **He feels betrayed by his own brother.** Marie
> and Hank have no kids, you never see me talk about mothers or fathers
> or grandparents. Walt's his brother. And obviously, Hank feels like
> he's the tougher, older brother.

[In another interview](https://www.rollingstone.com/movies/movie-news/qa-breaking-bad-star-dean-norris-on-the-many-faces-of-hank-185794/) he says:

> Betsy Brandt and I have talked about that, too. We’ve always wondered. I don’t know why. **I always thought it wasn’t that that they didn’t want kids, it was that for some reason or another they couldn’t have kids**, because yeah, it does seem likely that they would. Maybe you can see that longing to have had a child when we have baby Holly in our house. We don’t linger on it, but just a tad of “It would have been nice to have our own.”
>
> **For me, that brings to it that “She’s all I’ve got, and I’m all she’s got” dynamic.** That’s something that we can work with and use. I think that’s part of the reason each of us puts up with the other’s bullshit. [Laughs] I never understood the Walt/Skyler attraction myself, but I really understand that Hank and Marie would go into battle for each other.

---

However, Betsy Brandt seemed too think at one time that there were [plans to elaborate on this subject](http://www.vulture.com/2012/07/breaking-bad-betsy-brandt-interview.html):

> Why don’t Hank and Marie have kids?
>
> I want to know too! I’m fine with
> them not. But this is one of the things I love about *Breaking Bad*: The
> things we don’t say, we deal with them without straight-on dealing
> with them. **It will be addressed, but not directly addressed, in an
> upcoming episode.**

But nothing came of that, AFAIK.

---

Reviewers also [speculate about this subject](http://www.capitalnewyork.com/article/culture/2013/08/8533015/breaking-bad-final-season-family-time):

> It’s always been interesting to me that Marie and Hank don’t have any
> kids, since they clearly like their niece and nephew so much. When
> Marie would babysit Holly, she’d joke that she was going to keep her
> forever. This is total conjecture but **I think that they’re childless
> not by choice but because they couldn’t have any**. Whether it’s because
> of Hank or Marie, it explains a lot of the relationship they have with
> Walt and Skyler. **Hank would see his being unable to have a kid as a
> symbol of not being a real man.** Hence the bravado. If it’s Marie who
> couldn’t have them, that inability seems to have manifested into a
> case of O.C.D. and steady need to diminish her sister. I’m sure she
> and Hank were trying to help when they took Walt Jr. and Holly in, but
> that doesn’t mean they didn’t feel a jolt of victory about being the
> ones whose marriage was healthy and intact while Skyler and Walt’s was
> collapsing. Walt’s not the only character who sees things in terms of
> winning and losing.

Another reviewer has [a different view](http://archive.fsunews.com/article/20130819/FSVIEW01/130819012/W-W-Heisenberg-Voldemort-Breaking-Bad-Season-5-Episode-10-recap):

> The dynamic between Skyler, Marie and her baby is by far one of the
> most peculiar of the episode—Marie, without children of her own, has
> always taken on a maternal role with her sister’s children, whether
> Skyler warrants it or not. Hank and Marie’s childless marriage is a
> plotline that isn’t at the forefront of the show, but has always
> lingered in the background.
>
> “You are not leaving this house with my daughter. Give her back to
> me!”
>
> “I’m trying to protect her.”
>
> “Protect her? How dare you, I am her mother!”
>
> Marie fiercely believes taking Holly away from dangerous and unfit
> parents is what’s best for her. It’s not out of spite or her incessant
> need to one-up Skyler, it’s a sincere concern for an endangered child.
> But **is her attempted kidnapping merely a result of genuine concern, or
> is there a tinge of jealousy in Marie? Why is it fair that Skyler gets
> to be a mother when she’s not even fit to parent? Marie may feel that
> she deserves to take care of Holly, not her suicidal, hysterical
> sister.**

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer. I believe there was no mentions of the Schwartzs situation in the interviews?

Comment: @contemplator I can't recall to have ever read any explanation. I'm a bit intrigued by that "It will be addressed, but not directly addressed, in an upcoming episode." quote; would be nice if she could return to that subject in a future interview.